# Loop over bytes of a file in python and add without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x

While there's a good deal of questions on here about looping over bytes in a file and adding bytes without overwriting, I haven't been able to put any of the solutions from those together. How can I iterate over each byte of a file and then add a byte for each byte, without overwriting other bytes? Example, where the operation on each byte is just duplication:

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
```

would become

```
0x00 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x02 0x02 0x03 0x03
```

Comment: read the file, operate on the data, write the file

Comment: @KellyBundy I would, but nothing I've found has provided a way to loop over and insert bytes without overwriting. It could be something very obvious I'm missing, but I'm no python expert and don't really understand its internal data formats.

Comment: For example `bytes(b for b in b'\0\1\2\3' for _ in range(2))`.

Comment: Don't you have to write a new file?

Comment: @KellyBundy I have no idea why this works, but it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @KellyBundy Apologies, it appears I spoke too soon. It seems that the function is overwriting the original byte as well as creating the new byte. If my function is duplication, this is fine, but for a more complicated function, I want to leave the original byte intact as well. For example, if my function increments b, then `\01` becomes `\02 \02` rather than `\01 \02`.

Comment: `bytes(b for b in b'\0\1\2\3' for b in [b, b+1])`

Comment: @KellyBundy Aha, perfect! Thank you very much!